# How to set the chapter title in center of the page?

Tags: spacing

I want to set (Chapter 1 Introduction) and (Chapter 2 Protective Relay) only in the center of the page, I try to use `\vspace*{}` and `\vfill` but unfortuntly It isn't work, My code is:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{sectsty}
\chapterfont{\huge\sc\centering}
\chaptertitlefont{\centering}
\begin{document}

\chapter*{List of Abbreviations}
test
\newpage
\chapter*{List of Tables}
test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
\newpage
\chapter{Introduction}
\newpage
test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
\chapter{Protective Relays}
\newpage
test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Do you want the chapter title to be on a separate page, like part?

Comment: Yes, chapter (number & title) on separate page and in the center on the page, show the previous picture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have put (Chapter 1 Introduction) and (Chapter 2 Protective Relay) only in the center of the page. After you must use `\textsc` instead of `\sc`. I hope that I solved your problem.

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\huge\sc\centering}{\vspace{5cm}\centering\chaptertitlename \thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}
{0pt}{50pt}{10pt}



\begin{document}

\chapter*{List of Abbreviations}
test
\newpage


\chapter*{List of Tables}
test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
\newpage
\chapter{Introduction}
\newpage
test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
\chapter{Protective Relays}
\newpage
test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution with `titlesec`:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\usepackage{titlesec}

\begin{document}

\chapter*{List of Abbreviations}
test

\chapter*{List of Tables}

test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test

\titleclass{\chapter}{page}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\filcenter\bfseries\Huge}{\huge\textsc{\chaptername} \thechapter}{20pt}{}%[\break]%[\vfill]
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{6ex plus 1fill}{10ex plus 1fill}

\chapter{Introduction}

test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test

\chapter{Protective Relays}

test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test

\end{document}     \documentclass{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\usepackage{titlesec}

\begin{document}

\chapter*{List of Abbreviations}
test

\chapter*{List of Tables}

test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test

\titleclass{\chapter}{page}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\filcenter\bfseries\Huge}{\huge\textsc{\chaptername} \thechapter}{20pt}{}%[\break]%[\vfill]
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{6ex plus 1fill}{10ex plus 1fill}

\chapter{Introduction}

test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test

\chapter{Protective Relays}

test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1. Very nice and very fast instead of my code.

Comment: Thanks, @Sebastiano! Your code is also fine, except one detail: I'm not sure sectsty does not conflict with titlesec.

Comment: Into my short comment there is the comment of `\sc` :-(. I left it so otherwise the user could get into confusion.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I overlooked it, only looked at your code. I has time to delete that part of my comment :-)

Comment: Don't excuse yourself no need. If you think you're changing my code as I've written to you many times you're authorized.